# Synchronize threads' creation and destruction of (static) object

Tags: c++, multithreading, static

<sub>Awful title, I know, but (for now) I can't come up with something better</sub>

---

Suppose I have several objects, instances of class like this:

```
class MyWorker: public Thread
{
public:
    void Reconnect(...);
    //...
private:
    void DoDisconnect();
    ConnectionPtr m_ptrConnection;
};
```

Each of these objects are separate threads. `ConnectionPtr` is a reference counting smart pointer.

`Reconnect` first executes `DoDisconnect`, which just annuls `m_ptrConnection` (to decrease the reference counter), then executes `ConnectionFactory::Create` :

```
class ConnectionFactory
{
private:
    ConnectionFactory();

public:
    ConnectionPtr Create( ... );

private:
    //...
    void Destroy();
    static m_mutex;
    static ConnectionPtr m_ptrConnection;
};
```

Here, `Create( ... )` calls `Destroy()` and after that, reinitializes the `m_ptrConnection` member and returns it as a result.

The idea is, that all instances of `MyWorker` will use the same `Connection` (it's not important what this really is).

The problem is the following: all instances of `MyWorker` MUST call their `DoDisconnect` first (to decrease the reference counter) and then execute `Create` (when `Create` is executing `Destroy`, the reference counter for the `Connection` must be 1 (just the static pointer should be non-NULL) ).

Ideas how can I make this possible?

<sub>Sounds like a bad design and "too localized", I know. I can't change the design of `MyWorker` and the fact, that `Reconnect` calls `DoDisconnect` first. I can slightly change the desing of `ConnectioFactory`, if someone has a better idea.</sub>

---

<sub>Currently, I lock the static `mutex` to sync the access to `m_ptrConnection`. `Create` will just return if `m_ptrConnection` is already reinitialized by some other thread.

The only problem is, how to make sure, that all `MyWorker` threads have executed their `DoDisconnect` first? Using second `mutex` somehow? Or some static thread-safe (atomic) counter?</sub>

Comment: Grrrr, I can't explain this in a better and shorter way..

Comment: if I understand your question correctly, you can simply add a thread barrier after `DoDisconnect`, and just before `Destroy`.

Comment: @user2k5 - what is thread barrier? (sounds like this is what I need, but still)

Comment: a barrier would block the thread until certain number of threads have arrived the synchronization point. You may take a look at the [boost implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/boost/thread/barrier.hpp) for some idea.

Comment: @user2k5 - would you post your comment (may be a little expanded) as an answer? I'll accept it. This is what I really need. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From comments of the question]

You can insert a *thread barrier* between `DoDisConnect` and `Destroy` to ensure all the threads have finished `DoDisconnect` before `Destroy`. To get some idea, you may take a look at the [boost implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/boost/thread/barrier.hpp), which uses `mutex` and `condition_variable`.